# How to enable pop-up for lineChart when chartValueSelected using ios-chart API in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I started to learn how to use iOS-charts-API from appcoda.com

I create a LineChart and I don't know how to enable a small pop-up, with the value of the selected entry. Here is two example picture what I am trying to implement: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PhilJay/MPChart/master/screenshots/simpledesign_barchart3.png

[linechart entry selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GveGL.png)

If I tap on an entry I want to create a popup over it with its value.
I implemented chartValueSelected function:

```
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight){
print(entry.value)
print(highlight.xIndex)}
```

If I run this and tap on an entry, this code is working, so I can see the value on Console, but I think to create a pop-up is a built in function in the API, just I don't know what function should I call or property set.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? If so, would you be able to add some code examples to your question of the working solution? Been attempting to do the same for a while with no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This popup can be implmented by `ChartMarker`. Check out ChartsDemo's code, there is a `BalloonMarker` to demonstrate.

You should walk through `ChartMarker` class to know what can be done, like directly using a UIImage.